# How to make both text and background color highlight on hover?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, background-color

I am trying to create a grid style portfolio page in which the title highlights when hovered over. I would like also a background color to show over the image as well. I have created both of these but can't figure out how to have them happen at the same time. Below is the HTML and CSS as well as the link to see what I mean in action.

```
.home_blog_box { position: relative; float: left; width: 287px; padding: 0 12px 12px 0; }
.home_blog_box img { width: 287px; height: 201px;  }
.home_blog_box h3 { position:absolute; width: 287px; height: 201px; bottom:3px; left:0px;}
.home_blog_box h3:hover {background-color: #777777; opacity:.85;}
.home_blog_box h3 a {opacity:0; color:#ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-size:30px;}
.home_blog_box h3 a:hover {opacity:1}


<div class="home_blog_box">
<?php } ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-blog'); ?></a>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</div><!--//home_blog_box-->
```

Thanks!

Comment: oh and the site is http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this nicely with the :after or :before pseudo elements: http://jsfiddle.net/TpfA8/

example:

```
<div class="image-box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
  <p>title</p>
</div>
```

and relevant css:

```
.image-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}

.image-box:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(200,100,100, 0.5);
}

.image-box p {
  display: none;
}

.image-box:hover p {
 display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left; 10px;
}
```

Using CSS-generated content, you're creating a box around around the content of '' (nothing) but this element still adheres to the box model (sort of) so it can get things like height, width, position, etc.

Make sure to specify width for your image container so you can use the overflow: hidden; property.

Comment: that is helpful but I am struggling to translate that to having both the image and text as a link to the post. Any suggestions? also when I add the .image-box p {display:none;} or in my case .home_blog_box a {display: none;} it makes all of the images disappear. With it out the highlight box is displayed over the images but no title. And none of it is a link.

Comment: You could change the `p` title to the anchor. http://jsfiddle.net/TpfA8/4/ Then use :before instead of :after so the position happens correctly. Also, keep in mind that :before and :after aren't supported in every browser so wrap the image in an anchor as well for a fall-back if the hover + title doesn't work. You could also get into some modernizr feature detection combined with CSS classes but that's a different question and answer :)